# How can you process attributes inside a class but outside a method in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, exec

For a requirement I need to be able to use given arguments to create new methods. For example if an argument is ['a','b'] I would like to iterate through this list and create a an new method using the exec statment. 
For Example:
exec('def get_'+ arg1 +'(self): return self.' + arg1)
The result would be a new method object.get_argument. I can't figure out how to access object attributes outside of a new method and I don't think you can define a method inside another method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.args = args

    for arg in self.args
        exec('def get_'+ arg +'(self): return self.' + arg)

foo = Test(['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: You can't. Those attributes don't exist until you have an instance, so you can't do anything with them before you've even finished creating the class. Also you don't need getters in Python and should probably not be using `exec`. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

To change an object's attributes you can access its `__dict__`.  This example mimics what I think you asked for, and it sets all new attributes to the value `None`. But hopefully it makes the idea clear.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,*args):
        for arg in args:
            self.__dict__[arg]=None
            self.__dict__['get_'+arg]=lambda :self.__getattribute__(arg)

foo=Test('a','b','c')
foo.b
foo.get_a()
```

Instead of using a `lambda` function you can define a full-blown function inside your method and then assign that function to an attribute in `self.__dict__`